# Optional whitespace in regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to create a regexp to specify words between parenthesis. For example, I have a string like this:

```
"something(a,b)"
```

and

```
"something(c, d)"
```

and I want to extract the letters from between the parentheses.

In the first string I want to get an array `['a','b']`. In the second, I want the array `['c','d']`.

I have following method:

```
def suffixes(t)
  (t.scan /\((\w+),(\w+)\)/).flatten
end
```

but this works only for the first case. In the second variant I have:

```
def suffixes(t)
  (t.scan /\((\w+),[\s](\w+)\)/).flatten
end
```

But this works only for the second case. I don't know what regexp will operate in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the inbetween `\s` as optional.

```
def suffixes(t)
  (t.scan /\((\w+),\s?(\w+)\)/).flatten
end
```

`?` after the `\s` would turn the space to optional (*0 or 1*).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
def suffixes(t)
  (t.scan /\((\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\)/).flatten
end
```

`\s*` will match 0 or more spaces before and after comma.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to distinguish "scanning" for the text between parentheses and "splitting" the result by comma:

```
s = "something(c, d)"
s.match( /\((.+)\)/ )[1] # found text between parentheses
 .split(/,/)             # split the result by comma
 .map(&:strip)           # stripped the values
```

It’s more Ruby-like, in my understanding. Hope it helps.

**UPD** Thanks @theTinMan, there are two possibilities to improve an answer. First of all, `s[/\((.+)\)/, 1]` looks better ans executes faster than `s.match( /\((.+)\)/ )[1]`. Secondary, splitting by string is faster than splitting by regexp. The summing up:

```
s = "something(c, d)"
s[ /\((.+)\)/, 1 ] # found text between parentheses
 .split(',')       # split the result by comma
 .map(&:strip)     # stripped the values
```

Proof:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000
s = "something(c, d)" 

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { n.times { s.match( /\((.+)\)/ )[1].split(/,/).map(&:strip) } } 
  x.report { n.times { s.match( /\((.+)\)/ )[1].split(',').map(&:strip) } } 
  x.report { n.times { s[/\((.+)\)/, 1].split(/,/).map(&:strip) } } 
  x.report { n.times { s[/\((.+)\)/, 1].split(',').map(&:strip) } } 
end

#       user     system      total        real
#   3.590000   0.000000   3.590000 (  3.598151)
#   3.030000   0.000000   3.030000 (  3.028137)
#   2.940000   0.000000   2.940000 (  2.942490)
#   2.180000   0.000000   2.180000 (  2.182447)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `s[/\((.+)\)/, 1].split(',').map(&:strip)`. It's over 2x faster in my tests.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, it is even looks more readable. I updated an answer with all four variants and benchmarks.

Comment: Good benchmark. It's always interesting to see the results and to learn what are the fastest ways to do things. Also, look at using Fruity for your benchmarks as it handles a lot of the dirty work for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
\((\w+)|(?!^)\G\s*,\s*(\w+)
```

Try this.This will work for all arguments.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/27